# Show variable value by hovering mouse in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

Is there any way to show the variable value during debugging just by hovering the mouse pointer over the variable (like in visual studio)?

A plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was [some work](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/2368) to try to implement this in the past, but unfortunately it was not finished.

So this is not possible in Spyder at the moment (July of 2017).